# Some problems with xslt and ul with xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a problem. I have to show on the screen a list inside a xml with a xslt like html. The thing is that it only shows the first parameter. The problem is that I cannot use javascript or variables, but I have no idea. Thanks, here's the code

The xml:

```
 <UsuariosDestacados>
        <Usuario>Jonathan Joestar</Usuario>
        <Usuario>Joseph Joestar</Usuario>
        <Usuario>Will Anthonio Zeppeli</Usuario>
        <Usuario>Ceaser Zeppeli</Usuario>
    </UsuariosDestacados>
```

An here is the xsl

```
<h3>Usuarios destacados</h3>
<ul>
   <xsl:for-each select="Hamon/UsuariosDestacados">
       <li><xsl:value-of select="Usuario"/></li>
   </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

An here is the output:

Usuarios destacados

•Jonathan Joestar

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing (!) you want to do:

```
   <xsl:for-each select="Hamon/UsuariosDestacados/Usuario">
       <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
   </xsl:for-each>
```

I can only guess, because you did not post a reproducible example.